# Curl of electric field goes to infinity on the boundary of a charged conductor

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vector-fields

A charged conducting sphere in vacuum produces an electric field that is non zero outside of it and zero inside. Well inside both of these regions the curl of the electric field is zero.

But if we try to compute the curl exactly on the boundary of the surface, it will go to infinity due to the abrupt jump of electric field from zero to some finite value.

But this contradicts that 'the curl of an electrostatic field should be zero'!

Can anyone please show me my error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure about the fact that the curl of the electrostatic field diverges?
If you write the curl in spherical coordinates
(check here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates ) you realize that it vanishes identically. The point is that, writing the electric field produced by the sphere in spherical coordinates, the only non vanishing component is the radial part which only depends on the radial coordinates: $\vec{E}(r,\theta,\phi) = E_r(r)\hat{u}_r$, being $\hat{u}(r)$ the radial unit vector. Since the curl only involves derivatives of the radial component with respect to angular variables, then it vanishes.

The derivative of $E_r(r)$ with respect to $r$, which in this case is peaked at the charged sphere radius $r=R$ enters in the divergence of the field. The delta peaked divergence is consistent with Maxwell equations since it signals the presence of a surface charge.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What if we try to find the curl in Cartesian coordinates? Furthermore is it even reasonable to define a derivative of an discontinuous function?

Comment: About the derivative of discontinuous function, it makes sense in a mathematical framework known as "theory of distributions" (very roughly one can say that the derivative of a discontinuous function is a Dirac delta function). Regarding the calculation in cartesian coordinates, I honestly don't know what happens, because it's a really messy calculation, but it should still be zero, right? So maybe the derivatives cancel out before you evaluate them at the sphere surface... just guessing though

Comment: Why I asked about Cartesian is that the discontinuity comes into play directly rather than the cancellation that appears in spherical.

Comment: Yes sure, I understand your doubt, and I've never done such calculation... unfortunately keeping cartesian coordinates makes the calculation really messy. My guess is that the divergencies coming from the derivation of discontinuous functions should cancel out because of the - signs in the curl, so that in the end you get 0, recovering the same calculation done in different coordinates

Comment: Agreed that they might cancel, but a derivative of a function having singularities is worrying me.